# R - argument length is zero

Tags: r

I've tried looking at other questions but none quite hits the mark. I am trying to compare two rows and depending on the result of the comparison add a number in a new column at the end of the row. I am using mtcars:

The code I use is simply this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mtcars)-1) {
    if (mtcars[i,6] > mtcars[i+1,6] ){
    mtcars[i,12] = 5
    }
}
```

Where col 12 is a new column. I get the following error messages:

```
Error in if (mtcars[i, 6] < mtcars[i + 1, 6]) mtcars[i, 12] = 10 : argument is of length zero
```

There shouldn't be any null arguments so I have no clue what is returning a null argument and why this is an issue.

Thanks
John

Comment: Please post a sample of your data.

Comment: `parentheses` are your friends.  Look at `1:nrow(mtcars)-1`

Comment: The data is mtcars ... it is built in to R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `1:nrow(mtcars)-1`

Compare that with `1:(nrow(mtcars)-1)`
`# Note the parens aroud the right-hand-side of ':'`

The error comes from trying to take `mtcars[0, ]` which will be a zero-length vector, which in turn messes up your `if` clause

---

```
> 1:nrow(mtcars)-1
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
[25] 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
> 1:(nrow(mtcars)-1)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
[25] 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Comment: Beat my by a few +1.  I might add to the OP that I figured this out by placing a `browser()` at line 2.  `browser()` is a good programmer friend.